# If a function $f$ is not analytic at a point $a$, can we conclude that $f^2$ will not be analytic at $a$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, laurent-series

I am trying to show that an isolated singular point of a function $f$ is also an isolated singular point of $f^2$.  Can we show that $f^2$ is also not analytic or do I have to go about it using Laurent Series?

Comment: @UmbertoP. But we're looking at an *isolated* singularity here.

Comment: In view of Umberto's comment, you should tell more about the function $f$. What exactly do we know about it?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks. Once again I'm guilty of reading the title and not the question!

Comment: @UmbertoP. No sweat. I do it all the time, myself.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  hank you.  That was very helpful. Theres nothing given about f.  The full question is "Suppose z0 ∈ C is an isolated singular point of the function f of a given
type (removable, pole of order N, essential). Show that z0 is an isolated
singular point of h(z) = f$^2$(z) and find its type" so for a removable singularity how would I have to go about it?  I saw a similar proof where the removable case was broken up into the extension of f at z0 being 0 and the extension of at z0 being nonzero, but I'm not quite sure how to apply that here or if thats even the right thing to.

Comment: Well, the problem is wrong about removable singularities, unless it demands that a function be *undefined* at a removable singularity. But that is not the usual definition. The second paragraph of my answer gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An analytic function with an non-removable isolated singularity is unbounded near the singularity. Hence, so is $f^2$.

Of course, if the singularity is *removable*, it is quite different: Consider $f(z)=1$ everywhere except $f(0)=-1$, for example.